# How can I compare numerical strings in C?

Tags: c

I was having an issue in my program when comparing two numerical strings. I'm using strcmp right now but when comparing it thinks that 4 > 24 since it's comparing the first character. Is there a different way of comparing two numerical strings?

Note: My string can't contain a negative number!

Example of string I'm trying to compare:

```
"4 HelloWorld", 
"24 HelloWorld2"
```

I want the second string the be bigger since 24>4

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to solve:

```
int sort_string(const void *string1, const void *string2)
{
    char *const *p1 = string1;
    char *const *p2 = string2;
    return strcmp(*p2, *p1);
}
```

Comment: Pad the shorter string with leading zeros, so both are the same length, before comparing them.

Comment: One way would be to first convert them to numbers, then do an ordinary numeric comparison.

Comment: More problems for negative numbers. `strcmp` makes a lexicographical comparison.

Comment: For such small and simple numbers as shown in your example, then do what @TomKarzes suggests. Use `strtoul` to convert the leading number part of the string into an actual (unsigned) integer. Then compare the integer values instead.

Comment: `strtok()` on space -> `atoi()` on the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this fits into your requirements, but you can use feature of `atoi()` that it stops to convert string after first non-numeric character. Also it ignores leading spaces.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sort_string(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return atoi(*(const char **)a) - atoi(*(const char **)b);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *text[] = {
        "24 HelloWorld2",
        "4 HelloWorld",
        " 50 HelloWorld3",
        "1 HelloWorld4",
        "100 HelloWorld5",
    };

    qsort(text, 
          sizeof(text)/sizeof(*text),
          sizeof(*text),
          sort_string);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(text)/sizeof(*text); ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", text[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 HelloWorld4
4 HelloWorld
24 HelloWorld2
 50 HelloWorld3
100 HelloWorld5
```

Comment: return atoi(*(const char **)a) - atoi(*(const char **)b); that's exactly what I was missing! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If the data conforms to the samples provided - always positive digit sequence followed by non-digit (and then maybe more stuff):

```
char *p1 = strchr( str1, ' ' );
char *p2 = strchr( str2, ' ' );
if( p1 && p2 && (res = (p1-str1) - (p2-str2) ) == 0 )
    res = strcmp( str1, str2 );
return res;
```

The "longer" string of digits will represent the larger base10 value.

If the single option of a 'space' is too limited, `strspn( strX, "0123456789" );` could be used instead.

(Note: this method is not restricted to the finite number of bits available datatypes of `unsigned int`, or `unsigned long long`. Note, too, that this method, allowing, for instance, "ABCDEF" would also work for (single case) hexadecimal values, and, allowing "." could be extended to work for left justified floating point values where "42.70" would be regarded as less than "420.7", as it should be, without conversion to a built-in datatype.)

Caveat: `4` is expressed as `4`, not `0000000004`... Depends on the data, naturally...

Although it seems trivial, converting base 10 to base 2 may be expensive in terms of execution time.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with the program I'm trying to run. Thank you though!

Comment: @beezzyy This method will work with the data you presented... As to the late modification to the OP, promoting and then dereferencing a pointer (while casting, too) isn't going to buy you much toward solving your stated problem.